# Graph color conjuction mathematica

Tags: education

In the image, I split the graph of h[x] into 4 different graphs that show h[x] in different intervals with different colors. Is there anyway to show the entire function in one graph but have the sections be color coded like in the split versions?Each section of the graph would have a distinct color[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler method would be to use `Show` with the appropriate setting for `PlotRange`:

```
h[x_] := x^2 - 4 x + 7 Cos[x]

{plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4} = 
  { Plot[h[x], {x, -4, -1.49}, PlotStyle -> Magenta],
    Plot[h[x], {x, -1.49, -1.07}, PlotStyle -> Green],
    Plot[h[x], {x, -1.07, 2.89}, PlotStyle -> Cyan],
    Plot[h[x], {x, 2.89, 4}, PlotStyle -> Yellow]
  };

Show[plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0,0}]
```

[image: (plot to come)]

Answer (score 6):

```
h[x_] := x^2 - 4 x + 7 Cos[x]

mesh = {-1.49, -1.07, 2.89};
meshshading = {Magenta, Green, Cyan, Yellow};

Plot[h[x], {x, -4, 4}, 
 Mesh -> {mesh}, 
 MeshStyle -> None,
 MeshShading -> meshshading, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Butt"], AbsoluteThickness[5]]]
```

[image]

An alternative method is to use the inputs `mesh` and `meshshading` to construct a custom `ColorFunction`:

```
cf[x_] := Piecewise[Thread[{meshshading, 
    Join[{x <= mesh[[1]]}, 
        LessEqual[#, x, #2] & @@@ Partition[mesh, 2, 1], 
        {x >= mesh[[-1]]}]}]]

Plot[h[x], {x, -4, 4}, 
 ColorFunction -> (cf[#] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Butt"], AbsoluteThickness[5]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A brute force approach using [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

h[x_] := x^2 - 4 x + 7 Cos[x]
```

I darkened the `Yellow` and switched the order of the colors to separate the `Green` and `Cyan` which are difficult to distinguish.

```
Plot[
 Evaluate[
  ConditionalExpression[h[x], #] & /@
   (Simplify[
     Between[x, #] & /@
      Partition[{-4, -1.49, -1.07, 2.89, 4}, 2, 1]])],
 {x, -4, 4},
 PlotStyle -> {Magenta, Green, Darker[Yellow, 0.05], Cyan}]
```

[image]